# Proving a hash function family is weakly universal

Tags: probability-theory, hash

> $H$ is a family of weakly universal hash functions if for two elements $x,y$:
>
> $$ P(h(x) = h(y)) \le \frac1m, $$
>
> where $m$ is the size of the domain, and $h$ is chosen at random from $H$.

Given a hash family, how could one prove that it *is* weakly universal. I understand how to prove it isn't (proof by counter-example) but I cannot find any examples for when it is.

I apologise if this is a duplicate of another question. I was not able to find any examples online specifically for weakly universal hash functions.

Comment: See here: https://iuuk.mff.cuni.cz/~vesely/vyuka/1718/apx-06-en.pdf.

Comment: You prove it by proving that the inequality above holds.  Without knowing any specifics about what particular hash function you are dealing with, it's hard to say much more.